# Como hacer que la tabla en angular material se cargue en base a el estado y no traiga todos los datos

Tags: mysql, angular, material, typeorm

este es el codigo que use, quiero que la tabla me traiga solo lo relacionado a un dato en especifico, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo que no sea por getById, ya que traera todos los valores con un estado de pendiente u otro estado

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.vtSvc.getAll()
     .subscribe((ventas) => {
       this.dataSource.data = ventas;
     });
}
soloUno(): void {
 this.vtSvc.getAll()
    .subscribe((ventas) => {
      const busca = ventas.find((ventas) => (ventas.estado = 'PENDIENTE'));
      let { campana } = busca;
      this.isTodo = campana;
       });
}
```

Comment: Hola, podrías dar mas contexto a tu pregunta? Por ejemplo que es `this.vtSvc` . Si puedes agregar el código de todo tu componente para saber como ayudarte

Comment: Ya solucionado Gracias

Comment: Si solucionaste el problema entonces agrega una respuesta con tu solución. Así ayudas a las demas personas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola espero que te ayude

Este metodo quedaria igual ya que veo no es el objetivo.

```js
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.vtSvc.getAll().subscribe((ventas) => {
            this.dataSource.data = ventas;
        });
    }
```

cambiariamos un poco el metodo de SoloUno()...

```js
    soloUno(): void {
        this.vtSvc.getAll()
        .pipe(map(ventas => _.findWhere(ventas, { EstadoName: "PENDIENTE" })))
        .subscribe(res => this.isTodo = res);
    }
```

El metodo de _.findWhere() te retorna exactamente el objeto en donde se encuentre una comparacion de otro modos **undefined**

Utilice las librerias de [Rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) y [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#)

Aca hice un pequeño ejemplo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdt7jm?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

## Nota

En el ejemplo como no tenia un servicio hice un Observable para poder hacer un ejemplo lo mas cercano a lo que necesitas.

Te recomendaria que mejor lo manejaras por ID

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!